# Convert word to pdf using free third party dll

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, pdf, ms-word

I want to convert word document to pdf.

i found lots of solution using office dll. But i want a solution using free third party dll because in office dll there must be office installed. so on my server there is'n office installed.

Is there any free third party dll???

Comment: Ya... and do not install office on server. it's not a server product. you will run into problems sooner or later.

Answer (score 6):

EDIT: Oops, looks like you do have to have office installed.  One of the comments in the second link mentions using OpenXmlPowerTools.HtmlConvertor and iTextSharp to convert the document into HTML, and then going to a PDF.  Good luck with that!

If you're using .docx files, check out DocX:

http://docx.codeplex.com/

Then take a look at this blog post for an example on using DocX to convert to PDF:

[Converting .docx into (.doc, .pdf, .html)](http://cathalscorner.blogspot.com/2009/10/converting-docx-into-doc-pdf-html.html)

Hope this helps.  I'm not aware of any free solutions that will work with older versions of Word (.doc).

Comment: Hi danimal i think using itextsharp is long way to work because convert word to html and then to pdf.. no other way to do directly word to pdf???

Comment: I am not able to find free third party dll which conver from word to HTML. U have any Idea???

Comment: Eric White posted several articles on converting OpenXML documents to HTML.  Unfortunately it looks like a lot of work.  [View the posts here.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericwhite/archive/2008/10/20/eric-white-s-blog-s-table-of-contents.aspx#Open_XML_to_XHtml)

Comment: Also, a [video about the OpenXML Doc Viewer](http://youtu.be/WYZZ1_VXmNI) which lets you view a .docx in a browser.  Doc viewer can be [found here](http://openxmlviewer.codeplex.com/).