# How to convert .doc to .htm programatically?

Tags: c#, .doc

I want to convert `.doc` to `.htm` in C#. If I use `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word` I get the exception :

> Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID
>   {000209FF-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following
>   error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG))

Any solutions?

[The possibe duplicate is this: [C# convert .doc to .htm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5850499/c-sharp-convert-doc-to-htm), but it does not solve my problem.]

Comment: You can show your code here..

Comment: do you have ms-office installed on your machine..?

Comment: I dont have a code for this right now, but I got the code for converting doc to .xps and for this I think I would need the same libraries, the very first line has a problem:
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application wordApplication = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();

Comment: Yes I have the Starter Version 2010.

Comment: Okay I have figured out that the Starter Version of Word does not support the COM libraries, so is there a work around this problem? or is there a way to cnvert doc to htm without using Microsoft.Interop.Word ?

Comment: @user1340852 - The solution is not to use the Starter version of Word if you want to use the Office COM library.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is to read the doc/docx file using 3rd party dll and then write the data to html format using `HtmlTextWriter`

check out this stackoverflow questions:

[Convert word to pdf using free third party dll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10442772/convert-word-to-pdf-using-free-third-party-dll)

[Reading doc and docx files using C# without having MS Office installed on server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14455268/reading-doc-and-docx-files-using-c-sharp-without-having-ms-office-installed-on-s)

The links provided in the above questions are:

for docx:

http://docx.codeplex.com/

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb656295%28office.12%29.aspx

for doc:

http://npoi.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

The CLSID `{000209FF-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}` of the object needs to be in the registry.

The interop assemblies are wrappers that use the COM dlls provided by MS Office. So at some layer you use COM, although it's transparent to you.

Please check if you installed the interop stuff for MS Office.See this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa159923%28office.11%29.aspx
You can check if you have the interop assemblies for MS Word installed.